# TCPDF Three column layout

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, tcpdf

Since TCPDF does not support most of the style I have quite a problem.
My first idea was to solve it using a table, but this option must abandon because it is then possible to easily generate content.
I have a variable content, as well as an additional variable which is what size it should have.

More will try to describe the picture.

[image]

because it will use more times I can do it firmly. If you need to add something width3 class and then the next parameter width6 at it on one line. The whole content will vary accordingly. All that I can do the tables, I really do want to avoid. Because I have all the data in the field. I'd like it because solved some other way. Really thank everyone for help

So the code should look something like this

```
<div class="width3"><h2>nadpis</h2><p>Loren inpuls</p><p>Loren inpuls</p></div>
<div class="width6"><h2>nadpis</h2><p>Loren inpuls</p><p>Loren inpuls</p></div>
<div class="width3"><h2>nadpis</h2><p>Loren inpuls</p><p>Loren inpuls</p></div>
<div class="width3"><h2>nadpis</h2><p>Loren inpuls</p><p>Loren inpuls</p></div>
<div class="width3"><h2>nadpis</h2><p>Loren inpuls</p><p>Loren inpuls</p></div>
```

Comment: For clarification, I have all the values in the fields. A type of the cell 1 in the figure wherein it may consist of multiple lines. I'm in the field as [0] - title and in [1] value. It would have znemná I always make it conditional tr neuzvařelo, but concluded until needed for the next parameter and do not capture how much they will be on the line. Surely it would be possible, but I find it utterly useless when it's 100% can do something simple that it will add a class.

Comment: Use normal `Cell`s in TCPDF and do not try to abuse TCPDF to understand your HTML. It is a bit more work, but you have a control of your layout.